# How to get $d\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2(t)\right)$ from Ito's formula for Brownian motion?

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have a question about Ito's formula for Brownian motion. If we have the following diffusion equation
$$
dX_t=u(t,X_t)dt+v(t,X_t)dB_t
$$

Consider the inner product of $X_t$, which is $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2(t)$. So what  is
$$
d<X, X>_t=d\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2(t)\right)=?
$$

I know Ito's formula for multi-dimensional B.M. that is for $Y_t=g(t, X_t)$, then
$$
dX_t=\frac{\partial g_k}{\partial t}(t,x)dt+\sum_i \frac{\partial g_k}{\partial x_i}(t,x)dX_i+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 g_k}{\partial x_ix_j}dX_idX_j
$$

Comment: Apply Itô's formula to $g(x) = \sum_{i =1}^n x_i^2$.